# The holes in our ceiling junction box are not parallel to the walls. Do I have options other than removing the junction box?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling, junction-box

The base of the new ceiling light is a 30” x 9” rectangle. Mounting it as the bracket currently sits would look really bad—not at all square to the room.

I don’t need the hole moved much; maybe an inch would be enough. I tried looking for a bracket that might work but came up empty. Sometimes that’s because I can’t find it and sometimes it’s because it’s a bad idea.

Any and all help appreciated!

Here’s a picture of the bracket. The red line is roughly parallel to the wall.

[image: ceiling bracket with square line]

Comment: I had the exact same issue, don't won't to provide an ans without more information.  How is the fixtures mounted to the outlet box?  Does it have it own mounting plate that is attached to the outlet?  Provide picture of mounting plate if there is one or describe how fixtures is attached to this outlet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try an adaptor (universal crossbar) (adjustable swivel crossbar)

Or just live with it as is?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need. I’m not sure why I couldn’t find it (although I did give up early thinking “it’s probably a bad idea and so no one makes it.”)

Comment: you can get those at HD or Lowes.

Comment: I'm a little surprised the fixture didn't come with one of these already...